# I am trying to create TabRow with android compose kotlin. I couldn't add background color to tabrow. How can i do that?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-compose

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val tabItems = listOf("Diziler", "Filmler", "Keşfet", "Profil")
            val pagerState = rememberPagerState()


            ButtomNavigationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(){
                    Column() {

                        TabRow(

                            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                            backgroundColor = Malibu,
                            //PROBLEM IN HERE. BACKGROUNDCOLOR IS RED
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 20.dp).background(color = Color.Transparent)

                        ){

                        }
```

background color = Malibu is red. Do I miss to import something?
I dont know what to do. Or can I do this in a different way?
[this is the image of red error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un9lH.png)

[these are my imports. I couldnt add in code because it was too long for the stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHuni.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the `containerColor` and `contententColor` separately. There is no `backgroundColor` in the [Material3 version of `TabRow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TabRow(kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0)).

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    containerColor: Color = TabRowDefaults.containerColor,
    contentColor: Color = TabRowDefaults.contentColor,
    ...
): Unit
```